# Django and multiple joins

Tags: python, django, join, orm

I'm trying to do a quite long join, but it seems like django can't handle the last layer. Am I getting it wrong or is there any way around this?

Models.py

```
class A(models.Model):
    object_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class B(models.Model):
    class_A_object = models.ForeignKey(A, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class C(models.Model):
    class_B_object = models.ForeignKey(B, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

class D(models.Model):
    value= models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    class_C_object = models.ForeignKey(C, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

I'm then trying to select the value in class D when the related class A object name = ABC.

```
D.objects.filter(class_C_object__class_B_object__class_A_object__name='ABC')
```

This fails, to begin with pycharm refuses the autocomplete it and if I run it i get a name not defined error.

However, if i drop one layer it works.

```
D.objects.filter(class_C_object__class_B_object__value='ABC')
```

I haven't found any documentation mentioning a maximum number of joins, but it feels like there is a limitation here.

Does anyone know if that's the case, and if so, what the best way would be to work around this?

The database is external to me and can not be modified. The only working decent workaround i have at the moment is to use the cursor directly and write the sql by hand. However, this is not ideal for a lot of reasons.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Kind Regards, 
Peter

Comment: Post your exact error traceback

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this, maybe not the neatest solution, but by getting a queryset of A matching name ABC and then using that queryset for a __in filter on D get the result I want, and it's just doing one query.

It works, and is efficient, but the code is not very clean. If anyone has a suggestion of another way to do this i would be very happy to hear.

Thanks, 
Peter